# Points of interest within a specific radius

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dataframes, df1 (stores) and df2 (points of interest), each containing latitude and longitude data. For each store in df1, I would like to use the haversine function and count points of interest from df2 within a specific radius. Could you please advise the best approach, given df1 contains around 5000 rows and df2 around 200000 rows? Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6367 * c
    return km


df1 = pd.read_excel (r'Stores.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel (r'POI.xlsx')
```

Comment: Your `haversine` method returns the distance between the geodetic pairs, so you'd need to update it to determine if the points are within the desired radius. From there you could vectorize this method and have it broadcast between the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframes are represented as numpy arrays as follows:

```
>>> df1.shape
(5000, 2)
>>> df2.shape
(200000, 2)
```

Where each item in the arrays is a coordinate pair of `[lon, lat]`, then:

```
def knn(p1: np.ndarray, p2: np.ndarray, eps: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """Compute the boolean array for the k-nearest-neighbors.

    :param np.ndarray p1: reference points of size M
    :param np.ndarray p2: inspection points of size N
    :param float eps: desired epsilon in km
    :return: an M x N boolean array
    :rtype: np.ndarray
    """

    p1r = np.radians(p1)  # shape (5000, 2)
    p2r = np.radians(p2)  # shape (200000, 2)

    p1r = p1r[..., None, :]  # shape (5000, 1, 2)
    p2r = p2r[None, ...]     # shape (1, 200000, 2)

    dlon = p2r[..., 0] - p1r[..., 0]  # shape (5000, 200000)
    dlat = p2r[..., 1] - p1r[..., 1]  # shape (5000, 200000)

    a = ((np.sin(dlat / 2.0) ** 2) + 
         np.cos(p1r[..., 1]) * 
         np.cos(p2r[..., 1]) * 
         (np.sin(dlon / 2.0) ** 2))  # shape(5000, 200000)
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))  # shape(5000, 200000)
    km = 6371 * c  # shape(5000, 200000)

    return km <= eps
```

Now if you are using double-precision floats (`np.float64`), with your array this can become very expensive in memory space. In the example above, you'd have the following memory needs:

```
>>> p1r.nbytes
80000 (5000 * 2 * 8)
>>> p2r.nbytes
3200000 (200000 * 2 * 8)
>>> dlon.nbytes
8000000000 (5000 * 200000 * 8)
>>> dlat.nbytes
8000000000 (5000 * 200000 * 8)
>>> a.nbytes
8000000000 (5000 * 200000 * 8)
>>> c.nbytes
8000000000 (5000 * 200000 * 8)
>>> km.nbytes
8000000000 (5000 * 200000 * 8)
```

The result (returned as an array by `km <= eps`) only uses 1000000000 bytes since its a boolean array which uses only 1 byte per item. To save on memory, you have 3 options:

1. Process your dataframe in chunks
2. Store your coordinates using 32-bit floats
3. Combine some operations in your method

The combined operations method (condensed in lines) looks like:

```
def knn(p1: np.ndarray, p2: np.ndarray, eps: float) -> np.ndarray:
    """Compute the boolean array for the k-nearest-neighbors.

    :param np.ndarray p1: reference points of size M
    :param np.ndarray p2: inspection points of size N
    :param float eps: desired epsilon in km
    :return: an M x N boolean array
    :rtype: np.ndarray
    """

    p1r = np.radians(p1)[..., None, :]
    p2r = np.radians(p2)[None, ...]

    a = ((np.sin((p2r[..., 0] - p1r[..., 0]) / 2.0) ** 2) + 
         np.cos(p1r[..., 1]) * 
         np.cos(p2r[..., 1]) * 
         (np.sin((p2r[..., 1] - p1r[..., 1]) / 2.0) ** 2))

    return (6371 * 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))) <= eps
```

The resulting array as a mapping equivalent to:

```
              df2_point_1    df2_point_2    ...    df_point_n
df1_point_1        T              F                    T
df1_point_2        T              T                    F
...
df1_point_M        F              F                    T
```

Essentially its a truth table of whether or not a point in `df2` is within a specified epsilon of a point in `df1`. You can now do something with them in a manner such as:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    p1 = df1[i]  # point in df1
    n = df2[results[i]]  # the T/F act as a mask; returns T values
    print(f'Point {p1} has {len(n)} neighbors within {eps} km. They are: ')
    for j in range(len(n)):
        print(f'Neighbor {n[i]}')
```